# Laravel y AdminLte 3.0.5

Tags: laravel, adminlte

Estoy usando AdminLTE v 3.0.5 con Laravel 7 y la he integrado de forma manual, copiando las carpetas dist y plugins a una subcarpeta de la carpeta public en el momento que abro el DashBoard me cargan todos los archivo excepto las siguiente rutas http://localhost:8080/pos/assets/dist/js/demo.js y http://localhost:8080/pos/assets/plugins/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.min.js y verifico que los archivos esten alli y por supuesto alli estan pero laravel no me los carga, la forma en que los llamo es

- src="{{ asset('assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"
- src="{{asset('assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js')
  }}
- **src="{{asset('assets/plugins/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.min.js')
  }}"**
- src="{{ asset('assets/dist/js/adminlte.min.js') }}"
- **src="{{ asset('assets/dist/js/demo.js') }}"**

alguien podría ayudarme con este datalle, no encuentro solución y llevo bastante rato ya en esto, los que no cargan son los que estan en negrita

Comment: Todo lo pusiste dentro de una carpeta assets?

Comment: Si, todo lo puse dentro de esa carpeta

Comment: Si los encierras dentro de un <script> verdad?